# How to use Postgres & MongoDB simultaneously in Django?

Tags: django, mongodb, postgresql

I am looking for a solution to work with Postgres and MongoDB simultaneously in my Django project.

I have large data which I would like to store in MongoDB and Postgres for user management, billing, and other things to manage.

I have tried to use a library ```pip install djongo`` [djongo](https://pypi.org/project/djongo/), which is outdated, and not able to find any solution. Please guide me with an authentic solution! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

First of all, To install a newer version of Django you can use `pip install Django==<version>`, But you need to see compatibility with the Python version you're running on your system and virtual environment.
e.g. For Python 3.x, I'm using a bit older Django version `2.2.21`.

Second, Django does not support MongoDB natively, But `MongoDB` team themselves provides a library called `pymongo` which you can install, but with `pymongo` you'll have to write more of a native `mongodb` queries. They do not have any Django ORM.

But there's another library called `mongoengine` which is actually built on top of `pymongo` and is very handy and close to the ORM Django provides for relational databases.

Thirdly, About `Postgres` you can easily set up any relational database with Django as it provides native support for relational databases. Both the database are completely independent of each other, So there should not be any problem with the setup.

I, myself use `Postgres`  and `MongoDB` together in my projects, Never faced a single problem. Although, sometimes it's a little challenging to build things for NoSQL databases in Django which Django already provides for relational databases but yeah a little extra code as overriding Django base classes to provide support for `mongodb` always works.